# How read the bandwidth limit parameter from Tor with Stem

Tags: python, tor

How could one read the Tor parameter for bandwidth limit using Stem? I've looked around theAPI and could'n find a method or GETINFO parameter to such a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you mean the maximum bandwidth you've configured your relay for it's...

```
from stem.control import Controller

from stem.util.str_tools import get_size_label

with Controller.from_port() as controller:
  controller.authenticate()

  bw_rate = get_size_label(int(controller.get_conf('BandwidthRate', '0')))
  bw_burst = get_size_label(int(controller.get_conf('BandwidthBurst', '0')))
  print "you're configured to relay at most %s/s, with bursts up to %s/s" % (bw_rate, bw_burst)
```

... for example...

```
% python scrap.py 
you're configured to relay at most 1 GB/s, with bursts up to 1 GB/s
```

The git repository also has a new [get_effective_rate() method](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.get_effective_rate) which takes additional configuration attributes into account.